# Insert NaN DataFrame values in Clickhouse with 0 instead of NaN

Tags: sql, pandas, clickhouse

I'm trying to insert DataFrame via client.insert_dataframe command in clickhouse and DEFAULT 0 for column doesn't work, i keep getting NaN in my not nullable Int or Float columns

I want to replace NaN values without doing anything with DF itself cuz it will affect speed (or not but maybe there is solution on driver or create table lvl)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your schema and code please?